# Using regex capture groups from both the location and rewrite?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Given some example like:

```
location ~ ^/([\d]+)/ {
    rewrite ^/[\d]+/([\d]+)/(.*)$ #replacement
    
    proxy_pass https://httpbin.org/anything/$1/$2/$3 # ?

}
```

What would the capture groups be? Does nginx replace them? Merge them? Would I have 3 capture groups in that case? What would the ordering be?

It's unclear to me how I would reference each of the 3 capture groups above.

The final place I'm referencing the capture groups is in a proxy_pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numeric captures are reset each time Nginx evaluates another regular expression.

The numeric captures from the `location` expression are lost by the time the `proxy_pass` statement is evaluated. Only `$1` and `$2` are defined, and these are taken from the `rewrite` expression.

To make a capture persist across multiple regular expressions, give it a name using the `(?<name>...)` syntax.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/(?<name>[\d]+)/ {
    rewrite ^/[\d]+/([\d]+)/(.*)$ ...;        
    proxy_pass https://httpbin.org/anything/$name/$1/$2;
}
```