# Nginx Proxy Pass using location regex

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have nginx configuration like this

```
    location ~ ^/(900[0-9]|90[1-9][0-9]|9100) {
        rewrite ^/(?:(900[0-9]|90[1-9][0-9]|9100))/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.2.5:$1;
    }
```

but when I access 192.168.2.5:9180/9100 this is the
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a8Qr.png)

when I use nginx configuration like this

```
    location ~ ^/(900[0-9]|90[1-9][0-9]|9100) {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.2.5:$1;
    }
```

he succeeded but he wouldn't load the display because he didn't do the right GET request ie
**http://192.168.2.5:9180/asset/vendor.css**
which it should be
**http://192.168.2.5:9100/asset/vendor.css** or maybe **http://192.168.2.5:9180/9100/asset/vendor.css**

this is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuF74.png)

is there something wrong with my nginx configuration or maybe someone knows the correct way? can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: `$1` gets overwritten by the `rewrite` statement. You should use a named capture.

Comment: @RichardSmith Can you provide an example of the configuration?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74961957/4862445).